# Error: bad instruction 'rfe lr' arm cross compiler

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, arm, embedded

Attempting to compile 3rd party bootstrap which includes some assembly .S code which they supplied the tools (gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.03 using arm-linux-gnueabihf-) for a Cortex A5 mpu, but I'm running into a bad instruction for:

```
rfe lr
```

It appears that `rfe` is supported, so I'm wondering if it's a compiler issue? 
They claim they can compile using the same tools, but the updates were rather outdated. Their guide included the need for:

```
1. sudo apt-get install build-essential git-core libncurses5-dev
2. sudo apt-get install flex bison texinfo zip unzip zlib1g-dev gettext
3. sudo apt-get install gperf libsdl-dev libesd0-dev libwxgtk2.6-dev
4. sudo apt-get install uboot-mkimage
5. sudo apt-get install g++ xz-utils
```

However what I could locate ended up being:

1. "libwxgtk2.6-dev" replaced with "libwxgtk3.0-dev"
2. "uboot-mkimage" replaced with "u-boot-tools"
3. Had to add "lib32z1"

Everything else installed fine. (Using Ubuntu 16.04)

Output:

```
~/at91bootstrap$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- mrproper
  CLEAN        obj and misc files!
  CLEAN        configuration files!
  CLEAN        binary files!


~/at91bootstrap$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- sama5d4eksd_uboot_defconfig
#
# configuration written to .config
#
#
# make dependencies written to .auto.deps
# See top of this file before playing with this auto-preprequisites!
#

~/at91bootstrap$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
CC
========
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc 4.7.3

as FLAGS
========
... 
.
.
.
AS        ~/at91bootstrap/driver/svc_handler.S
CC        ~/at91bootstrap/driver/svc_mgr.c
AS        ~/at91bootstrap/driver/monitor/mon_init.S
AS        ~/at91bootstrap/driver/monitor/mon_switch.S
~/at91bootstrap/driver/monitor/mon_switch.S
~/at91bootstrap/driver/monitor/mon_switch.S: Assembler messages:
~/at91bootstrap/driver/monitor/mon_switch.S:94: Error: bad instruction `rfe lr'
~/at91bootstrap/driver/monitor/mon_switch.S:170: Error: bad instruction `rfe lr'
Makefile:297: recipe for target ~/at91bootstrap/driver/monitor/mon_switch.o' failed
make: *** [~/at91bootstrap/driver/monitor/mon_switch.o] Error 1
```

Comment: what are the command line options when using gcc or gas these can/will determine which instruction set is used or it supports.

Comment: is this in line assembly or real assembly?

Comment: ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueablihf-

Comment: it's real assembly. One of the included files in the bootstrap is a .S file.

Comment: Their guide says to use "ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueablihf-" or just using "make <mpu device>_deconfig" which is odd because when I use the mfgr version of this bootstrap (which is the original they branched from) we use "arm-linux-gnueabi-" Which is odd because the mfgr version uses "gnueabi" but the 3rd party version uses the hard float "gnueabihf" for the exact same device.

Comment: It may be useful to include the code generating the error - not just the single instruction, and the build-log including the assembler invocation and the error message - that is all useful diagnostic information you can see but we cannot.  Copy & Paste it into your question - do not paraphrase it or add the information in a comment.

Comment: please provide a minimal example that demonstrates the problem including the complete command lines for the tools used.

Comment: Added output above.

Comment: The git repository location/ sources revision for the code you are trying to compile would help as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem. Procedure: create a file named rfe.S

```
.text
.thumb
 rfe lr
.end
```

gcc 4.7.3:

```
/opt/linaro/4.7.3/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -dumpversion 
4.7.3
/opt/linaro/4.7.3/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a5 -c -o rfe.o rfe.S
rfe.S: Assembler messages:
rfe.S:3: Error: bad instruction `rfe lr'
```

The good new is that 7.2.1 is working fine, that is you could in the worst case modify your build procedure for compiling the offending .S files using 7.2.1:

```
/opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-eabi/bin/arm-eabi-gcc -dumpversion
7.2.1
/opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-eabi/bin/arm-eabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a5 -c -o rfe.o rfe.S
/opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-eabi/bin/arm-eabi-objdump -d rfe.o

rfe.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e99e c000       rfeia   lr
```

rfe.S does assemble as well when using the 32 bits instruction set:

```
.text
.arm
 rfe lr
.end


/opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-eabi/bin/arm-eabi-objdump -d rfe.o

rfe.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   f89e0a00        rfeia   lr
```

This may be a symtom that the code you are trying to compile does require a different toochain that the one you think was required.
I would advise trying to use a [7.2.1 Linaro toolchain](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz), if you are lucky, your code will compile as is. If not, try to assemble the offending files with 7.2.1.

I hope this answer helps you.